# SmartCard reader: Building libccid

Tags: usb, fedora, libusb, udev, pcsc

I am trying to build libccid, pcsclite and libusb together on a fedora 20. I have been able to compile and build libusb and pcsclite. However, while building libccid, I get the following error in the build log:

copy the src/92_pcscd_ccid.rules file in udev directory (/etc/udev/rules.d/)

I did copy the file to the specified location and then ran the makefile. However, I have not had any success.

Did anyone come across this error message?

Thanks

Comment: Is that a real error message you are getting? Because it does not look like error at all.

Comment: This is what I get in the logs:***************

copy the src/92_pcscd_ccid.rules file in udev directory (/etc/udev/rules.d/)

***************

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check the [libccid source code](http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/pcsclite/trunk/Drivers/ccid/src/Makefile.am?view=markup) you will find out that it is not an error message. It is just an informational message that you should manually copy file `92_pcscd_ccid.rules` from `src` directory to `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory.

Comment: Thanks...Does that mean the build process is complete? Because when I run a "make install" it does not install the binaries in a 'lib' directory nor does it create a 'include' directory to include the header files.

Comment: @ap6491 It is really hard to say as I don't know much details about your build process.